# Android Repo tool fails to init default.xml when <include ... /> statement is used

Tags: git, repo

When using the repo tool to include other manifest files it fails.

Unfortunately from the logs it seems to have an issue parsing the files.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

I've tried initializing each manifest.xml individually with success but as soon as I merge them using the include statement it fails.

I have tried pointing to the manifest file explicitly only to have the same result.

`repo init -u https://github.com/example/Manifest -b master`
`repo init -u https://github.com/example/Manifest -b master -m default.xml`

The file structure is:

```
- default.xml
- /scripts/filea.xml
- /scripts/fileb.xml
```

## default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<manifest>
  <remote fetch="https://github.com/example" name="origin"/>
  <default sync-j="4" revision="refs/heads/master" remote="origin"/>

  <remote fetch="https://git.yoctoproject.org/git" name="yocto"/>
  <remote fetch="https://github.com/mendersoftware" name="mender"/>
  <remote fetch="https://github.com/openembedded" name="oe"/>

  <project remote="yocto" revision="thud" name="poky" path="sources/poky"/>
  <!-- <project remote="oe" revision="thud" name="meta-openembedded" path="sources/meta-openembedded"/> -->

  <include name="scripts/filea.xml"/>
  <include name="scripts/fileb.xml"/>

</manifest>
```

## filea.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<manifest>
  <default sync-j="4" revision="refs/heads/master"/>

  <remote fetch="https://github.com/example" name="origin"/>

  <project name="meta-kernel" remote="origin" revision="master" path="sources/meta-kernel"/>

</manifest>
```

## fileb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<manifest>
  <default sync-j="4" revision="refs/heads/master"/>

  <remote fetch="https://github.com/mendersoftware" name="mender"/>
  <remote fetch="https://github.com/example" name="origin"/>

  <project name="meta-mender" remote="mender" revision="thud" path="sources/meta-mender"/>
  <project name="meta-mender-community" remote="mender" revision="thud" path="sources/meta-mender-community"/>
  <project name="meta-mender-production" remote="origin" revision="master" path="sources/meta-mender-production"/>

</manifest>
```

Below is a snippet of the error output. From the look of it there's something wrong when parsing the default.xml but I'm struggling to figure out why.

```
From https://github.com/example/Manifest
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yocto/build/.repo/repo/main.py", line 572, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/yocto/build/.repo/repo/main.py", line 547, in _Main
    result = run()
  File "/home/yocto/build/.repo/repo/main.py", line 540, in <lambda>
    run = lambda: repo._Run(name, gopts, argv) or 0
  File "/home/yocto/build/.repo/repo/main.py", line 201, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/home/yocto/build/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 452, in Execute
    self._LinkManifest(opt.manifest_name)
  File "/home/yocto/build/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 309, in _LinkManifest
    self.manifest.Link(name)
  File "/home/yocto/build/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py", line 180, in Link
    self.Override(name)
  File "/home/yocto/build/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py", line 173, in Override
    self._Load()
  File "/home/yocto/build/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py", line 479, in _Load
    self._ParseManifest(nodes)
  File "/home/yocto/build/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py", line 546, in _ParseManifest
    elif new_default != self._default:
  File "/home/yocto/build/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py", line 74, in __ne__
    return self.__dict__ != other.__dict__
  File "/home/yocto/build/.repo/repo/manifest_xml.py", line 95, in __eq__
    return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `<default ... />` from included files (filea.xml and fileb.xml). At most one default element may be specified.

From repo documentation

```
$ repo help manifest
[...]
Element default

At most one default element may be specified. Its remote and revision
attributes are used when a project element does not specify its own
remote or revision attribute.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that fixed it.